# Upload Image tmp file on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to build a simple image upload script in PHP.

I'm getting "Upload complete!" but its not storing the image in my "uploads" directory on my server. I'm using an EC2 Instance on Amazon AWS.

Any ideas?

```html
<?php
//properties of the uploaded file
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$name = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
$name = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
$temp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];

if($error > 0) 
 die("Error uploading file!");

else {
 move_uploaded_file($temp, "uploads/".$name);
 echo "Upload complete!";
}
     

?>
```

Comment: May be ownership problem on ec2 instance, I had this similar problem before, Kindly check that folder is owned by which user, there will be two users: "apache" and "ec2-user", If it's owned by "ec2-user" then follow these steps mentioned in this [URL](http://blog.david-jensen.com/wordpress-amazon-ec2-apache-permissions-wordpress/)..

Comment: my var/www directory is owned by root:```drwxrwsr-x 7 root www 4096 Nov  8 16:39 /var/www```

Comment: For testing change it to ec2-user...

`sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/`

Comment: Hate to ask a question that is somewhat unrelated, but since you seemed to get to a point I am not even able to get to, how did you manage to get around the 405 when attempting to post a file to the ec2 server?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to with "405"?

Answer (score 0):

```
replace 
    $temp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp"];
    with 
    $temp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

and try.

you should have read, write permission to your created directory. otherwise the uploaded image will not place in your directory.

Comment: I actually did that too. (modified the original post). And still not uploading even though I can echo out the tmp directory and file. Still not moving it to my uploads directory.

Comment: do you have all permissions to your upload directory? read, write, execute?

Comment: I have 775 rights to the uploads folder. Is that my issue?

Comment: I changed the perms to that specific folder by doing: ```sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap_form/uploads```. That directory now has full rights but still not moving my image to it.

Answer (score 0):

OMG! What I get for copying and pasting. I had the $name variable set multiple times! Its fixed now. Thanks for the help!